# Definition of dev_attrs used in gpiolib-sysfs.c

Tags: c, linux-kernel, driver, gpio

I try to understand what's going on in linux kernel driver code, especially how virtual files in /sys/class/gpio/... are created. When inspecting drivers/gpio/gpiolib-sysfs.c I stumbled about these definitions at the bottom of the file:

```
static struct attribute *gpio_attrs[] = {
    &dev_attr_direction.attr,
    &dev_attr_edge.attr,
    &dev_attr_value.attr,
    &dev_attr_active_low.attr,
    NULL,
};
```

My question is: Where are these referenced objects (dev_attr_direction, dev_attr_edge, dev_attr_value, dev_attr_active_low) defined? I searched the whole kernel code, but could not find any definitions...

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a possible definition, e.g.

```
static DEVICE_ATTR(edge, 0644, gpio_edge_show, gpio_edge_store);
```

could be a precompiler macro that generates one of the doubtful definitions.
Just an idea.

Comment: Indeed you are right https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/device.h#L125